# How do you execute a command on an element of a control template?

Tags: wpf, uwp, binding, command, controltemplate

I want to build a custom control that uses a custom brush.  The idea is, when I execute a command on the custom control, I want it to filter down to a component in the template.  My first pass looks something like this:

```
<Style TargetType="trrfc:QuantityControl">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="trrfc:QuantityControl">
                <Border>
                    <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                                      VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}">
                        <ContentPresenter.Foreground>
                            <trrfc:AnimatedColorBrush StartColor="Red"
                                                      Animate="{Binding Mode=TwoWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource  TemplatedParent}, Path=Animate}"
                                                      Duration="00:00:05"/>
                        </ContentPresenter.Foreground>
                    </ContentPresenter>
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

That is, I want to execute the command on the **AnimatedColorBrush**.  Is this the right way to do it?

Comment: Please clarify what "filter down" means? What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: I am trying to execute the 'Animate' method on the AnimatedColorBrush control when a value is updated in the QuantityControl.

Comment: @Quarkly Hi, could Nico's answer be helpful to you? if you have any questions, please feel free to contact us

Answer (score 0):

> How do you execute a command on an element of a control?

For the scenario, you could use `InvokeCommandAction` where in the [`XamlBehaviors`](https://github.com/Microsoft/XamlBehaviors/wiki/InvokeCommandAction) library to approach.

For example, if you want to invoke command when the button click. you could use `EventTriggerBehavior` to detect click event then trigger `InvokeCommandAction` like the following.

```
<Button x:Name="MyButton">
    <Interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
        <Interactions:EventTriggerBehavior EventName="Click" SourceObject="{Binding ElementName=MyButton}">
            <Interactions:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding UpdateCountCommand}"/>
        </Interactions:EventTriggerBehavior>
    </Interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
</Button>
```